# The class 'ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule' was not found in the chain configured namespaces StudentsBundle\Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am making a application with multiply bundels and database connections.

**I keep getting this error:**
The class 'ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule' was not found in the chain configured namespaces StudentsBundle\Entity
500 Internal Server Error - MappingException

Here is the code from the controller

```
<?php
namespace ScheduleBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

//Json Response
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

//Class Controller
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

//Request
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/api/{week}")
   */
  public function roosterApi(Request $request, $week)
  {
    $rooster = array('week' => '1');


    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $roosterConnection = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ScheduleBundle:schedule', 'schedule');
    $dataRooster = $roosterConnection->findOneByStudentId('36838');


    $dataRooster->setSchedule($rooster);

    $entityManager->persist($dataRooster);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $out = array('1' => $week);

    return new JsonResponse($out, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
  }
}

?>
```

I think the problem is with my orm mapping so i include the doctrine code from config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: StudentDB
        connections:
            StudentDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_students%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            TeacherDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_teachers%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            GradesDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_grades%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            ScheduleDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_schedule%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            SpecialGroupDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_specialgroup%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            ToDoListDB:
                driver:   '%database_driver%'
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_todolist%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: students
        entity_managers:
            students:
                connection: StudentDB
                mappings:
                    StudentsBundle:  ~
            teachers:
                connection: TeacherDB
                mappings:
                    TeachersBundle: ~
            grades:
                connection: GradesDB
                mappings:
                    GradesBundle:  ~
            schedule:
                connection: ScheduleDB
                mappings:
                    ScheduleBundle: ~
            specialgroup:
                connection: SpecialGroupDB
                mappings:
                    SpecialGroupBundle:  ~
            todolist:
                connection: ToDoListDB
                mappings:
                    ToDoListBundle: ~
```

I am using symfony 3.0.3 and doctrine

edit: changed use ScheduleBundle\Entity to use ScheduleBundle\Entity\schedule this did not fix the problem

Comment: Your last `use` statement is missing the filename. `use ScheduleBundle\Entity\YourFileName`

Comment: hi this was not the problem will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct doctrine entity manager service. In your code you refer to the doctrine service which is an alias of the default entity manager. For the schedule entity manager you need to use the following service:

```
doctrine.orm.schedule_entity_manager
```

So try using this:

```
$this->get('doctrine.orm.schedule_entity_manager')
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->get('doctrine')
```

For dump current service definition you can use the console command:

```
app/console debug:container |grep entity
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer the error is gone but i get a new error instead: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getManager" of class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".

Comment: Hi fixed the problem i forgot to remove ->getManager() thank you for your help